# Find equation of a quadratic that passes through a point, given 2 slopes at 2 values of x

Tags: derivatives, indefinite-integrals

For my homework, I am supposed to find the quadratic (in y=ax^2 + bx + c form) that passes through (2,15) and has slopes of -8 and 4 at x=-1 and x=1 respectively.

I used the slope values given to find the slope (6) of the derivative equation, but I don't know how to make use of the fact that the quadratic passes through (2,15).

We have not learned integrals yet so simple integration (x -> x^2 / 2) isn't an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will get the equations $$15=4a+2b+c$$ and $$2a(-1)+b=-8$$ and $$2a+b=4$$